# Feature Selection for gene expression data

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

Can someone please give me some suggestions on which feature selection techniques for gene classification should I use?

Comment: This may be too broad and opinion-based for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem to work with gene expression data, with a large number of dimensions and small sample size. Instead of standard feature extraction/selection algorithms, generally, kernel-based feature selection algorithms are applied to gene expression data such as `KBMTL`(kernelized Bayesian multitask learning), `NDR`(nonlinear dimensionality reduction) or regularized linear methods such as `LASSO` and `Elastic-net`.

You can check these papers to learn more about how to make efficient feature selection on gene expression data.

[paper1](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/431734v1)

[paper2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187705091500561X)

[paper3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4147917/)